# ActiveMQ Network of Brokers results in high message sending latency

Tags: performance, jms, activemq-classic

Long time listener, first time caller on Stackoverflow :)

I have an ActiveMQ broker with a Producer and Consumer. The producer is connecting to an activeMQ broker. There is a consumer that is attached to the same broker. When I send the messages with this setup P -> B -> C there is little to no latency and the the messages are sent at the rate of 8ms per message.

Now I add another broker to create a network of brokers and send messages using the following configuration: P -> B1 -> B2 -> C it takes as much as 80ms per message.

Additional info:

P and B1 are in the same data center, DC1.

B2 and C are in the same data center, DC2.

DC1 and DC2 are two different data centers on the same coast with a ping latency of about 20-30ms.

I am using the default config that is shipped with the activemq tarball. The only configuration I added was for connecting the brokers to create a network of brokers.

On B1 I added the following configuration to activemq.xml

```
<networkConnectors>
</networkConnectors>
```

On B2 I added the following configuration to activemq.xml

```
<networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector name="B2" uri="static://(tcp://b1.prod.xxx.com:61616)" duplex="true"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

It is a full duplex connection and B2 is behind the firewall so works as advertised.

Any thoughts why the latency added is so much higher. The 10x latency is unacceptable. It could be worse when the number of producers increase.

What am I doing something wrong?

edit:

I see that sending the message from B1 to B2 is taking > 240ms per message. Here's some relevant info in the activemq.log

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,186** | TRACE | Running task iteration 932 - Transport Connection to: vm://broker1#0 | org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner:128 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,187** | DEBUG | bridging (broker1 -> broker2) ActiveMQBytesMessage {...} ActiveMQBytesMessage {...}, consumer: ID:broker1-50755-1373522507018-2:1:1:2, destination topic://LogMessageTopic.Server.xxx.com, brokerPath: [ID:broker1-50755-1373522507018-0:1], message: ActiveMQBytesMessage {...}  ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null } | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport:974 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,438** | TRACE | Running task iteration 933 - Transport Connection to: vm://broker1#0 | org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner:128 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,439** | DEBUG | bridging (broker1 -> broker2) ActiveMQBytesMessage {...} ActiveMQBytesMessage{...}, consumer: ID:broker1-50755-1373522507018-2:1:1:2, destination topic://LogMessageTopic.Server.xxx.com, brokerPath: [ID:broker1-50755-1373522507018-0:1], message: ActiveMQBytesMessage {...} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null } | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport:974 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,708** | TRACE | Running task iteration 934 - Transport Connection to: vm://broker1#0 | org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner:128 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,709** | DEBUG | bridging (broker1 -> broker2) ActiveMQBytesMessage {...} ActiveMQBytesMessage{...}, consumer: ID:broker1-50755-1373522507018-2:1:1:2, destination topic://LogMessageTopic.Server.xxx.com, brokerPath: [ID:broker1-50755-1373522507018-0:1], message: ActiveMQBytesMessage {...} ActiveMQBytesMessage{ bytesOut = null, dataOut = null, dataIn = null } | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport:974 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

**2013-07-10 23:05:00,962** | TRACE | Running task iteration 935 - Transport Connection to: vm://broker1#0 | org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner:128 | ActiveMQ BrokerService[broker1] Task-3

Seems like the broker to broker data transfer is taking a long time.

I tried setting persistent=false and removing using KahaDB without any success.

Comment: I have a few questions for clarification: 1) When you say "sent at the rate of 8ms per message" do you mean that you have a latency of 8ms per message or that you send a message every 8ms? 2) Assuming you mean a latency of 8ms (since you talk about 10x latency increase later) How is that possible when there is a latency of 20-30ms between B1 and C? Please clarify.

Comment: SirRichie, 1) That is correct. The latency between P and B1 is 8ms. 2) The latency is of 20-30ms is between B1 and B2 in DC1 and DC2.

Comment: I'm not really good at reading log files. From what I can identify, you're using vm:// as the transport protocol? You should definitely switch over to tcp:// ; also try sending TextMessage for testing purposes, not a ByteMessage; and question: how do you measure latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effects of store-and-forward in a broker network. When you send a message from P, it is:

- stored in B1 and confirmed to P as sent.
- B1 then forwards it to B2 which stores it and confirms to B1; B1 deletes the message from its local store.
- B2 then forwards the message to C. When C consumes it, it acknowledges the message to B2, which B2 deletes from its local store.

A message broker network is not transparent in the same way that regular networks are. The receiving and dispatching mechanisms on a broker are effectively seperated from each other by a message store, which is either on disk or in memory. Each broker is a stop on the way between the producer and a consumer. So in that respect I am not surprised to see a higher latency. I like the analogy that it's like a line of people passing a bucket of water.

See [Understanding ActiveMQ Broker Networks](http://www.jakubkorab.net/2011/11/understanding-activemq-broker-networks.html) for a more detailed explanation.